# Find and parse string between two same characters

Tags: vb.net

How would I parse a specific string between two "%"? For example, I would like to get "john" from smith%john%Michael. The position of the "%" can change because names can be at different lengths.

Comment: Is it possibile that a string has three `%` and some other has just one? I mean, are you absolutely sure that the strings have always two `%` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf`:

```
Dim firstIdx = yourString.IndexOf("%")
Dim lastIdx = yourString.LastIndexOf("%")
Dim between = yourString.SubString(firstIdx + 1, lastIdx - firstIdx - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim firstname = "smith%john%Michael".Split("%")(1)
'output = john
```